# how can we change the name of files of build artifacts in azure devops

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-devops

how can we change the name of files of build artifacts in azure devops
below is the picture.
i want to change the name of files in drop, want to add build number with the names.
[image]
eg WebApplication1_(buildNumber)

i use the sample project from visual studio, asp.core.webapp
[image]

also tell me from which file artifact files take the name of the file "WebApplication1".
i am using azure devops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just rename your files through PowerShell before publish them:

```
$projectName = 'WebApplication1'
$projectNewName = 'WebApplication1_$(Build.BuildNumber)'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) "$projectName.*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "$projectName","$projectNewName" }
```

The example:

[image]

The result:

[image]